# Unable to see radio button when set to android:choiceMode="singleChoice"

Tags: android, listview, radio-button

I have just seen the following [link](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/event-listener-for-a-listview-in-single-selection-mode/) which suits my needs and I am trying to find hard in getting the same thing worked for my listview. Hope someone can shed me some light on this

This is what the link has:

`android:choiceMode="singleChoice"` set for **`listview`** just to set single radio button selection

Now I have something similar to the above listview but with some images and textviews and nothing special.

Here is my listview:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background ="#CCCCCC">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="#3366CC"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp" 
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>
   <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
            android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_width="1dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical" 
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/divider"
            android:background="@drawable/buttons"
            android:text="Previous" 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:textSize="20sp"  
            android:textColor="#4285f4"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/buttons"
            android:text="Next" 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/divider"
             android:textSize="20sp"  
            android:textColor="#4285f4"/>
    </RelativeLayout>        
</LinearLayout>
```

Now my problem is I'm unable to get the radiobuttons beside them as shown in the above link.

And here is my row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
        android:textSize="14sp" 
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:textColor="#000000" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/itemDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
         android:focusable="false"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/price" 
        android:textSize="19sp" 
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:textColor="#003399" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/itemDescription"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The sample you link to uses `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice` for the rows. You are not. The radio buttons show up because the sample is using `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice` with a `singleChoice` `ListView`. `singleChoice` alone does not add radio buttons.

You need to create (or find) a custom `View` for your rows that implements the `Checkable` interface and has a suitable radio button in it, either by using `RadioButton` directly or by using `CheckedTextView`.

For example, [this blog post shows a `CheckedLinearLayout`](http://tokudu.com/post/50023900640/android-checkable-linear-layout), that leverages a `CheckedTextView` that you supply to offer the `Checkable` interface to work with a `singleChoice` `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to select single row out of all the entries in listview then dont use checkbox. use radiobutton only. dont use singlechoice listview because that is not supporting custom row, it will support android default layout only i.e. android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice. so it will better you create custom listview with radiobutton on each row. and through your code try to manage single selection. i think this will help you out to work better. if you need more help then pls tell me.